# Размер файла в input type="file"

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать новый файл и поставить его по умолчанию в input type="file".

Но размер нового файла не совпадает с размером старого, и картинка не прогружается.

Делаю я это с целью переименоавния файла.

```js
const mobile = document.querySelector('[files-mobile]');

mobile.addEventListener('change', renameFile);

function renameFile(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    const renamed = new File([event.target.value], 'mobile_version', {
        type = file.type,
        size = file.size,
    })

    const dt = new DataTransfer();
    dt.items.add(renamed)
    mobile.files = dt.files;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" files-mobile>
```